# How to access files images in documents directory in embedded html?

Tags: html-form-web-part

If I load anything to documents and have the following structure

```
Documents
|__img
|   |__logo.jpg
|
|__js
|   |__bootstrap
```

How do we access these images via `<img src="???"></img>` tag?

I've tried `<img src="Documents/img/logo.jpg"></img>` and `<img src="./Documents/img/logo.jpg"></img>`

but nothing seems to work. The current approach which isn't ideal, is to open the image in the sharepoint, and copy image address. But is there a way around it using relative paths?

The script itself that calls it (or html that references it) is embedded in the front page when you click edit. I'm not exactly sure where that is relative to the documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to use depends on the actual location of your document library, i.e. whether it is within a site collection, sub-site etc., and  its relative location to where you are calling it from.

For example, if your document library is in the root site collection for the web application 'https://webapp.domain.com', the full path to the image file would be 'https://webapp.domain.com/Documents/img/logo.jpg', however you can also reference this as '/Documents/img/logo.jpg' which references the root of the current web application (using the '/') for the browser to go back to before pulling items from further down the tree. If your document library is in a sub-site at 'https://webapp.domain.com/sub-site' then the full relative path to the image would be '/sub-site/Documents/img/logo.jpg' instead.

If your script is attempting to call the image file, you'll want to go back up a folder or two (depending on exactly where the script is in the structure) to reference the file, so if 'bootstrap' is the script doing the calling, it would need to be '../img/logo.jpg' to go back up a level to the document library, then back down a level into the 'img' folder to get at the image file.

However, if the script is being referenced in other pages and the page is doing the calling, then you will find it is always easier to use the full relative path to the image file as that allows you to avoid working out the current location within a web application before calling the image. Using a relative URL to the image file rather than an FQDN also allows for alternative access mappings to be used as well.